# Why we do not mentioned driver name in application.properties in spring boot when trying to connect database like oracle?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, configuration

I have seen if we declare below three properties  in the application. properties in spring boot , we are able to connect the oracle database through spring data jpa

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

spring.datasource.username=SYS as SYS DBA

spring.datasource.password=root
```

My Question is why we are not providing driver name here. IS this something that It is automatically mapped the driver name here?

Answer (score 0):

from documentation [Connection to a Production Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

> You often do not need to specify the driver-class-name, since Spring
>   Boot can deduce it for most databases from the url

Answer (score 0):

This `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation does the magic..Spring boot scans the `pom.xml` and build your project based on dependency added. So if you add oracle dependency then it will configure oracle driver for you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can infer from `spring.datasource.url` about which driver should be used.

Spring document says that :

> You often do not need to specify the driver-class-name, since Spring Boot can deduce it for most databases from the url.
>
> For a pooling DataSource to be created, we need to be able to verify that a valid Driver class is available, so we check for that before doing anything. In other words, if you set spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, then that class has to be loadable.